# Insert tailwindcss class value with php

Tags: php, css, variables, wordpress-theming, tailwind-css

I'm creating my first custom wordpress theme using [tailpress](https://tailpress.io/) and I managed to get value from wordpress customizer with get_theme_mod(). But when I try to insert this value into tailwind class declaration, rebuilt file doesn't recognize my class. It seems like browser displays it correctly, but PHP runs after tailwind classes are generated? Currently my code looks like this:

At the top of the file I get my PHP value:

```
<?php 
    // variables from theme-settings (customize)
    $GLOBALS['border_width'] = get_theme_mod('border_width_setting_id') 
?>
```

Then I insert it into tailwind class:

```
<div id="content" class="... border-x-[<?php echo $GLOBALS['border_width'] ?>px] ...">
```

In the browser looks OK:

[image: in the browser]

but this tailwind border class is only generated if I specify it in PHP file statically without using PHP, like this: `border-x-[80px]`. It doesn't work with dynamic PHP value as shown above. How can I get PHP and tailwind to work together? I heard it has something to do with PostCSS?

Comment: does it work after clearing cache & hard reload? (ctrl + f5)

Comment: I'm using cache free tab (turned off in chrome network tab) and browser-sync auto reload :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue with PHP. When working with [dynamic](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) classes Tailwind cannot read them on the fly as it is working with source files. So instead you may use style attribute for such dynamic values

```php
<div class="border-x-[line-width:var(--my-border)]" style="--my-border: <?php echo $GLOBALS['border_width'] ?>px">
```

or any other styling way. If you have predefined list of `border_width_setting_id` (like 40, 80, 120), you may [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) it

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your css variable example? How does this work with tailwind exactly? I haven't seen this earlier and it's not clear to me why we need `line-width:` part

Comment: Instead of hard-coded value you're passing CSS variable `var(--my-border)` - so your class name would not change (it always will be `border-x-[line-width:var(--my-border)]`) and Tailwind will be able to read it as it is during compilation. All you need to do is to set variable property within style attribute or anywhere else. `line-width:` is just modificator otherwise Tailwind will consider value as a color (like `border-red-500`)

Comment: I can add that: `When using arbitrary values in brackets, Tailwind converts the arbitrary value directly to a CSS property,`